# Program Type Already Present Glide

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I'm trying to load image from Firebase using Glide. I start to meet error when I trying to implement Glide. During gradle sync, everything is fine. But, when i clean and rebuild the program, it will show following error.

```
`Program type already present: com.bumptech.glide.gifdecoder.GifDecoder$BitmapProvider Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.bumptech.glide.gifdecoder.GifDecoder$BitmapProvider, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}`
```

I'm using sdk 26 as I met runtime error during use of sdk 27. I have made sure all the dependencies are not override sdk 27.

gradle:project

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven
            {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle: app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.uploadimage7"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
//implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have tried "exclude group: "com.android.support" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The error is solved by deleting the duplicate .jar in the libs folder

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to update your SDK to version 27 and do the following changes. First, update your gradle to the latest version `3.2.1`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Now change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.2.1'
```

And for Glide, please change this line:

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1"
```

to

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1"
```

Comment: Hi Haruko! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The problem has been solved by deleting the duplicate jar. However, the update of gradle in your answer do help me to implement sdk 27 without any runtime error. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Got the same build error after upgrading Glide from 3 to 4. Resolved by:

1. Quit Android Studio
2. Remove all build folders
3. Open the project again in Android Studio
4. Build it
5. Build succeeded